# MySQL Database is Indexed at Apache Solr, How to access it via URL

Tags: mysql, database, apache, solr, indexing

**data-config.xml**

```
<dataConfig>
 <dataSource encoding="UTF-8" type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somevisits" user="root" password=""/>
 <document name="somevisits">
  <entity name="login" query="select * from login">
   <field column="sv_id" name="sv_id" />
   <field column="sv_username" name="sv_username" />
  </entity>
 </document>
</dataConfig>
```

**schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
    <fields>
        <field name="sv_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
        <field name="sv_username" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
        <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
        <field name="text" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/> 
    </fields>
    <uniqueKey>sv_id</uniqueKey>
    <types>
        <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />
        <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    </types>
</schema>
```

Solr successfully imported mysql database using full http://[localSolr]:8983/solr/#/collection1/dataimport?command=full-import

**My question is, how to access that mysql imported database now?**

Comment: Do you want to know how to query your core, in general or how to fetch that fresh imported documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search your indexed data then following is the URL for searching indexed data.

```
http://[localSolr]:8983/solr/CORE_NAME/admin
```

This will open search interface. By default search string is *:* which will give all the indexed documents as result. Here first * stands for field name and second * stands for keyword. You can search a specific string for a specific field i.e username:USERNAME or sv_id:YOURID. Or if you just give a keyword without giving any field name "mykeyword", then it will search this keyword in your default search field.